# Apply background-image on <img> tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend

i have a qrcode image and i want to apply another background image behind this qrcode image on all media screens but it is only centralize on large screen.. and not working on others.

[image: ss of centralization not working in small screen]

here is my code :

html:

```
<style>
div.qrcode-frame
{
    height:414px;
    width:300px;
    background:url({{asset('QRblack.png')}}) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
}
    @media screen and(max-width:992px)
    {
        div.qrcode-frame
        {
             position: center;
            left: 5%;
        }
    }

@media screen and(max-width:600px)
{
    div.qrcode-frame
    {
        background-position-x: center;
    }
    
}

    img{
        width: 273px;
        height: 273px;
        padding: 13px;
    }
</style>

{{--    <div class="section-title products_title" data-aos="fade-up" >--}}
<div class="qrcode-frame" style="border: solid black;">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode($image) !!}"/>
</div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn-get-started scrollt btn" id="qrqen">Download QRcode</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: why is there no z-index?

Comment: Why would you need a z-index for this, @MVB76?

Comment: Where is the z-index in my code... My i put it mistakenly and did'nt know that it's z-index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add another element (e. g. a `div`) to the page, give it a background-image and place it behind your QR-code.

if you want to center it everything I recommend using `display: flex;`
This way your QR-code will always stay centered.

Have a look at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-river-pp31o?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: I am not at home right now... I will check your solution.. And then accept it.. Thanks